# why do I not see desktop cube option in compiz manager

Tags: compiz, cube

Ubuntu 14.04 on a new piece of hardware (Samsung laptop). I installed CompizConfig Settings Manager.

When I open CompizConfig manager → Desktop, I can see `Expo` for instance but no `Cube`. Why is that? Any ideas?

It has a core i7 processor. It should have the built-in chops to handle high scale graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you need to install synaptic manager for extra plugin options like cube on desktop features in compiz config manager.